# Laravel MySql driver with SSL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ssl

I am trying to connect to a SSL enabled database with a Laravel application, but when I do so, I get a bad gateway error.  Per a few different resources, I found the following configuration for the MySql driver to add support for SSL connections, but with this driver configuration, I get the Bad Gateway error.

## Driver

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
            'options'   => [
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    => '/path/to/file/ca.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT    => '/path/to/file/client-cert.pem',
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => '/path/to/file/client-key.pem'
            ],
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

I am using Laravel Valet as the development environment for this. I get the following error in the Valet NGINX error log: `2018/06/14 07:51:50 [error] 6495#0: *15 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ccc.dev, request: "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1"`

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue with a SSL enabled DB connection in a Laravel application or on Valet?

Comment: Is there mistype here `''/path/to/file/client-cert.pem'`? Double single quotes `''` in start of this line.

Comment: That was a copy and paste typo.  When I was removing my local file path, and replacing it with `/path/to/file/` I grabbed too much.  Will update post to remove the additional `'`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @Brady Charron? I’m struggling with the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

For me, it appeared to not need the cert or CA. Setting this worked:

```
 'sslmode' => 'require',
 'options' => [
     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/path/to/file/client-key.pem'
 ],
```